# Android, Java: Bundles & Views for Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, that i want to put a textview which will have a 3 strings stored in it from the 'Main Activity'

The strings that I need to pass will come from the Main Activity and will be passed into FragmentClass

The issue is that its not recognising findViewById, i understand this is something to do with the views? Could someone advise me on how i could get this editText working and then how i can pass a bundle of strings from the MainActivity to the FragmentClass.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {

    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //Inflate the layout for this fragment

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);


      //  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_data, container, false);
    TextView FragmentTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FragmentTextView);


   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);
TextView FragmentTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.FragmentTextView);
return view;
}
```

Also you have `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` you have suppressed lint warning. Probably indicates that some features are available in new api's only. Do check your min sdk version in manifest

Comment: Hi it works thanks, i just had to restart my eclipse. It was tripping..  Do you have any idea how i will take a bundle of strings from the MainActivity Class to the Fragment Class

Comment: @user3247335 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android